# How to push Android Project to existing private empty repository in github with Android Studio?

Tags: git, android-studio, github

I am trying to push android project to private empty repo with android studio . But I cannot find simple solution. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Github helpfully provides a guide for adding an existing code base into a repository which already exists, [here](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/).  Whilst not specific to android studio, it will allow you to use whatever normal commit method you use.

In a nutshell:

- navigate to your code repository
- run the command `git init`
- add the files to commit with `git add .`
- commit the changes : `git commit -m "your commit message"`
- add the remote origin : `git remote add origin your@git:repo/name`
- verify the remote URL `git remote -v`
- push the changes `git push origin master`

Answer (score 4):

To push an android studio project to an empty git, follow these steps:

1. Go to terminal and change working directory to your project root using `cd` command and enter below commands.
2. `git init`
3. `git status` -> This would output you list of files in red color.
4. `git add .` -> Adds all the files to local version control.
5. `git commit -m "Some Commit Message"`
6. `git remote add origin repository_url.git`
   Example: `git remote add origin https://github.com/ramakrishnajoshi/JetpackNavigationComponent.git`
7. `git push --set-upstream origin master` -> A new branch is created with name `master` and all the code will be pushed to this branch.
8. Wait till the code is pushed before doing any other operation in terminal.

After all this, you will get a message similar to `Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin`

Answer (score 2):

If you are pushing to a private repo in a local location ie. a private server.:

- Assuming you have set up local git repository, cd into the remote location and clone your local repository with `git clone 'path to local repo'`
- cloning will set the local repo as a remote, so we have to remove that with `git remote remove origin`
- make the remote repo bare with `git config --bool core.bare true`
- Then in your local repository add the remote with `git remote add origin 'location to remote git repo'`

Now you should be able to push to remote in Android studio.