# How to upload the android project to private github repository

Tags: git, github

I have created android app and my friend told me to upload the code to his private repository, I am not able to upload the code to it. I have followed 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35205479/how-to-push-android-project-to-existing-private-empty-repository-in-github-with) & [this](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/) I can see only root directory not inside files, please help...

Comment: Just use the terminal `git` commands not Android Studio...  Have you even setup a clone of the repo or added the remote yet? `git remote add origin **remote repository URL**`?

Comment: 1. After `git add .` run `git status` - Do you the files that going to be committed? 
2. After `git commit ...` run `git log -1` - Do you see your commit message?
3. Did you get any errors or warning for `git push ..`

Comment: @Libin Varghese git add . has added only root folder not inner folders

Comment: @RahulMatte what do you mean by "has added only root folder"?

Comment: @RahulMatte: By any chance do you have a .gitignore file. See if you are ignoring any subfolders or file patterns that you actually need tracking.